# Can not import vlc to python program

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, vlc

I'm trying to reproduce a video with sound in python Tkinter through VLC, but cannot run the file since I get an error when running the line import vlc.

I have python 3 at 32 bits, VLC player at 32 bits and installed it through `pip install python-VLC`, which was successful and then try to run the code and get this error:

```
File "C:/Users/momoh/Documents/GitHub/CNDH/CNDH.py", line 5, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\momoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 207, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\momoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 163, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
  File "C:\Users\momoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

This is the code that I´m tryin to run:
My imports:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk           
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import vlc
```

and the class for the frame that has the video

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=6)

        self.configure(background="white")


        # Open the video source |temporary
        self.video_source = "assetsCNDH/prueba.mp4"

        # Canvas where to draw video output
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width= controller.winfo_screenwidth(),
                                height=controller.winfo_screenheight(), bg="black",
                                    highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Creating VLC player
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()

    def GetHandle(self):
        # Getting frame ID
        return self.winfo_id()

    def play(self, _source):
        # Function to start player from given source
        Media = self.instance.media_new(_source)
        Media.get_mrl()
        self.player.set_media(Media)

        # self.player.play()
        self.player.set_hwnd(self.GetHandle())
        self.player.play()
```

How do I get my video running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using subprocess to run VLC through the CLI.

```
import subprocess


comand = 'vlc --play-and-exit --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video -f --one-instance --no-playlist-enqueue  assetsCNDH\\directorio.mp4'
subprocess.run(comand, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Python-vlc is a binding of python to vlc program (or wrapper libraries). It is a way to run vlc program via python (python -> binding -> vlc). It will not run the vlc program itself so you need to do the following steps:

```
1)  download vlc program and install it in your machine
2)  restart your machine
3)  run notebook again
```

You may download and install vlc (64-bit) in this link: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Reference:

```
https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding
```

quote:

> Note that this only installs the python module itself, which depends
> on the availability of the libvlc libraries. You must also install VLC
> itself to get these libraries.

Comment: I have already installed VLC in the same bits version as my python. But it can't find it. How do I give it to the import?

Comment: What plugins are needed so I give the direct path?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, For me the **32bit version was not working** even after adding its folder to the PATH environment variable, But installing the **64bit version solved the issue**!