Struggling with UI issues
I want to be able to resize my widget/windows with with the double arrows Window's style grab edge and resize them type functionality. I want to able to change height and width by dragging the edges of each window individually to adjust them. Any help on how to refine this script and suggestions on how to make it better would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the dependencies:
tkinter: The standard GUI toolkit for Python.
ttk: Provides themed widget set for tkinter.
messagebox: Part of the tkinter module, used for displaying dialog boxes.
filedialog: Part of the tkinter module, used for file dialogs.
yt_dlp: A youtube-dl fork for downloading YouTube videos.
vlc: Python bindings for the VLC media player.
os: Provides operating system dependent functionality.
random: Generates pseudo-random numbers.
json: Used for working with JSON data.
threading: Provides thread-based parallelism.
PIL: Python Imaging Library, used for image processing.
ImageTk: Part of PIL, used for displaying images in tkinter.
                                                      

Here is my script
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import vlc
import os
import random
import json
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class YouTubeJukebox(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



        self.title("YouTube Jukebox by Littch")
        
        # Detect screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # Set geometry to maximize the window
        self.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
        
        # Load background image
        self.bg_image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\dj-8562307.jpg")
        self.bg_image = self.bg_image.resize((screen_width, screen_height), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.bg_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bg_image)

        # Create a canvas and set the background image
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.bg_photo, anchor="nw")

        # VLC Instance and Player Setup
        self.vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.vlc_instance.media_player_new()
        self.player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.on_song_end)

        # Styling
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure('TButton', font=('Arial', 7), padding=5)
        style.map('TButton', foreground=[('pressed', 'white'), ('active', 'white')],
                  background=[('pressed', '#3498DB'), ('active', '#3498DB')])

        self.playlist_id_entry_style = {"bg": "#ECF0F1", "fg": "#34495E", "insertbackground": "#34495E"}
        self.playlist_id_label_style = {"bg": "#2C3E50", "fg": "#FFFFFF"}

        # Add widgets to the canvas
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter YouTube Playlist ID:", **self.playlist_id_label_style)
        self.label_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 50, anchor="center", window=self.label)

        self.playlist_id_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=50, **self.playlist_id_entry_style)
        self.entry_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 100, anchor="center", window=self.playlist_id_entry)

        self.load_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_playlist)
        self.load_button_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 150, anchor="center", window=self.load_button)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=80, height=15, bg="#424242", fg="#FFFFFF", selectbackground="#FF5722")
        self.listbox_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 300, anchor="center", window=self.listbox)

        self.controls_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#212121")
        self.controls_frame_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 450, anchor="center", window=self.controls_frame)

        button_style = {'width': 6, 'height': 1}

        self.play_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Play", command=self.play_selected)
        self.play_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.pause_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Pause", command=self.pause_audio)
        self.pause_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.play_all_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Play All", command=self.play_all)
        self.play_all_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_back_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Skip Back", command=self.skip_back)
        self.skip_back_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_forward_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Skip Forward", command=self.skip_forward)
        self.skip_forward_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.shuffle_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Shuffle", command=self.shuffle_playlist)
        self.shuffle_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Save Playlist", command=self.save_playlist)
        self.save_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.load_playlist_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_saved_playlist)
        self.load_playlist_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.volume_label = tk.Label(self, text="Volume:", fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
        self.volume_label_window = self.canvas.create_window(200, 500, anchor="center", window=self.volume_label)

        self.volume_slider = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.set_volume, length=300)
        self.volume_slider.set(50)
        self.volume_slider_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 550, anchor="center", window=self.volume_slider)

        self.equalizer_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#212121")
        self.equalizer_frame_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 600, anchor="center", window=self.equalizer_frame)

        self.equalizer = vlc.AudioEqualizer()
        self.create_equalizer_controls()

        self.playlist = None
        self.current_index = None
        self.audio_urls = []
        self.media_list = None
        self.media_player = None

        self.last_playlists_file = "last_playlists.json"
        self.last_playlists = []

        # Bindings for moving and resizing
        self.bind_events()

    def bind_events(self):
        for widget in [self.label, self.playlist_id_entry, self.load_button, self.listbox, self.controls_frame, self.volume_label, self.volume_slider, self.equalizer_frame]:
            widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_widget_click)
            widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
            widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)
            widget.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
            widget.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "widget": None}
        self.resize_data = {"resizing": False, "widget": None, "direction": None}

    def on_widget_click(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        self.drag_data["widget"] = widget
        self.drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self.drag_data["y"] = event.y
        if self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            self.resize_data["widget"] = widget

    def on_drag(self, event):
        widget = self.drag_data["widget"]
        if widget and not self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            x = widget.winfo_x() + event.x - self.drag_data["x"]
            y = widget.winfo_y() + event.y - self.drag_data["y"]
            widget.place(x=x, y=y)
        elif self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            self.resize_widget(event)

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.drag_data["widget"] = None
        self.resize_data["resizing"] = False

    def on_enter(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.update_idletasks()
        bbox = widget.winfo_geometry().split('+')[0].split('x')
        width = int(bbox[0])
        height = int(bbox[1])

        if abs(event.x - width) < 5 or abs(event.y - height) < 5:
            self.canvas.config(cursor="sizing")
            self.resize_data["resizing"] = True
        else:
            self.canvas.config(cursor="")

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(cursor="")

    def resize_widget(self, event):
        widget = self.resize_data["widget"]
        widget.update_idletasks()
        width = widget.winfo_width()
        height = widget.winfo_height()

        if abs(event.x - width) < 5:
            widget.config(width=event.x)
        elif abs(event.y - height) < 5:
            widget.config(height=event.y)

    def load_playlist(self):
        def load_playlist_async():
            try:
                playlist_id = self.playlist_id_entry.get().split('&')[0]
                if not playlist_id:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a valid playlist ID")
                    return

                playlist_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={playlist_id}"
                self.playlist = self.get_playlist_videos(playlist_url)

                self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
                for title in [video['title'] for video in self.playlist]:
                    self.listbox.insert(tk.END, title)

                self.current_index = 0
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading playlist: {e}")
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to load playlist: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=load_playlist_async).start()

    def get_playlist_videos(self, playlist_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'extract_flat': True,
            'quiet': True,
            'force_generic_extractor': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            result = ydl.extract_info(playlist_url, download=False)
            if 'entries' in result:
                return result['entries']
            else:
                return []

    def play_all(self):
        def play_all_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist first")
                    return
                self.current_index = 0
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_all: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_all_async).start()

    def play_selected(self):
        def play_selected_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist")
                    return
                selected_index = self.listbox.curselection()
                if selected_index:
                    self.current_index = selected_index[0]
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_selected: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_selected_async).start()

    def play_current_index(self):
        def play_current_index_async():
            try:
                if self.current_index is None or self.current_index >= len(self.playlist):
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a valid video")
                    return
                video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={self.playlist[self.current_index]['id']}"
                audio_url = self.get_best_audio_url(video_url)
                media = self.vlc_instance.media_new(audio_url)
                self.player.set_media(media)
                self.set_volume(self.volume_slider.get())
                self.player.play()
                self.highlight_current_song()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_current_index: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=play_current_index_async).start()

    def get_best_audio_url(self, video_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio',
            'quiet': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
            return info_dict['url']

    def highlight_current_song(self):
        try:
            self.listbox.select_clear(0, tk.END)
            self.listbox.select_set(self.current_index)
            self.listbox.activate(self.current_index)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in highlight_current_song: {e}")

    def pause_audio(self):
        try:
            if self.player.is_playing():
                self.player.pause()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in pause_audio: {e}")

    def on_song_end(self, event):
        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index < len(self.playlist):
            self.play_current_index()

    def skip_forward(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_forward: {e}")

    def skip_back(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index - 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_back: {e}")

    def shuffle_playlist(self):
        try:
            if self.playlist:
                random.shuffle(self.playlist)
                self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
                for video in self.playlist:
                    self.listbox.insert(tk.END, video['title'])
                self.current_index = 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in shuffle_playlist: {e}")

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        try:
            self.player.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in set_volume: {e}")

    def save_playlist(self):
        try:
            playlist_id = self.playlist_id_entry.get().split('&')[0]
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if playlist_id and playlist_id not in self.last_playlists:
                self.last_playlists.append(playlist_id)
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "w") as file:
                    json.dump(self.last_playlists, file)
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Playlist saved successfully")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Playlist is already saved")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in save_playlist: {e}")

    def load_last_playlists(self):
        try:
            if os.path.exists(self.last_playlists_file):
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "r") as file:
                    self.last_playlists = json.load(file)
            else:
                self.last_playlists = []
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_last_playlists: {e}")

    def load_saved_playlist(self):
        try:
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if not self.last_playlists:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "No saved playlists found")
                return

            playlist_id = random.choice(self.last_playlists)
            self.playlist_id_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.playlist_id_entry.insert(0, playlist_id)
            self.load_playlist()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_saved_playlist: {e}")

    def create_equalizer_controls(self):
        labels = ["60Hz", "170Hz", "310Hz", "600Hz", "1kHz", "3kHz", "6kHz", "12kHz", "14kHz", "16kHz"]
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            lbl = tk.Label(self.equalizer_frame, text=label, fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
            lbl.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

            scale = tk.Scale(self.equalizer_frame, from_=-20, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=70, command=lambda val, idx=i: self.set_equalizer_band(idx, val))
            scale.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

    def set_equalizer_band(self, band, value):
        try:
            self.equalizer.set_amp_at_index(float(value), band)
            self.player.set_equalizer(self.equalizer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error setting equalizer band: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = YouTubeJukebox()
    app.mainloop()



import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import os
# import vlc
import random
import json
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class YouTubeJukebox(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



        self.title("YouTube Jukebox by Littch")
        
        # Detect screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # Set geometry to maximize the window
        self.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
        
        # Load background image
        self.bg_image = Image.open(r"F:\\Wallpapers\\Desktop\\wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper (1).jpg")
        self.bg_image = self.bg_image.resize((screen_width, screen_height), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.bg_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bg_image)

        # Create a canvas and set the background image
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.bg_photo, anchor="nw")

        # VLC Instance and Player Setup
        # self.vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
        # self.player = self.vlc_instance.media_player_new()
        # self.player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.on_song_end)

        # Styling
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure('TButton', font=('Arial', 7), padding=5)
        style.map('TButton', foreground=[('pressed', 'white'), ('active', 'white')],
                  background=[('pressed', '#3498DB'), ('active', '#3498DB')])

        self.playlist_id_entry_style = {"bg": "#ECF0F1", "fg": "#34495E", "insertbackground": "#34495E"}
        self.playlist_id_label_style = {"bg": "#2C3E50", "fg": "#FFFFFF"}

        # Add widgets to the canvas
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter YouTube Playlist ID:", **self.playlist_id_label_style)
        self.label.place(x=screen_width/2, y=50, anchor="center")
        
        self.playlist_id_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=50, **self.playlist_id_entry_style)
        self.playlist_id_entry.place(x=screen_width/2, y=100, anchor="center")

        self.load_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_playlist)
        self.load_button.place(x=screen_width/2, y=150, anchor="center")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=80, height=15, bg="#424242", fg="#FFFFFF", selectbackground="#FF5722")
        self.listbox.place(x=screen_width/2, y=300, anchor="center")

        self.controls_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#212121")
        self.controls_frame.place(x=screen_width/2, y=450, anchor="center")
        button_style = {'width': 6, 'height': 1}

        self.play_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Play", command=self.play_selected)
        self.play_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.pause_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Pause", command=self.pause_audio)
        self.pause_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.play_all_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Play All", command=self.play_all)
        self.play_all_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_back_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Skip Back", command=self.skip_back)
        self.skip_back_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_forward_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Skip Forward", command=self.skip_forward)
        self.skip_forward_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.shuffle_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Shuffle", command=self.shuffle_playlist)
        self.shuffle_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Save Playlist", command=self.save_playlist)
        self.save_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.load_playlist_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_saved_playlist)
        self.load_playlist_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.volume_label = tk.Label(self, text="Volume:", fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
        self.volume_label.place(y=500, x=screen_width/2, anchor="e")
        #self.volume_label_window = self.canvas.create_window(200, 500, anchor="center", window=self.volume_label)

        self.volume_slider = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.set_volume, length=300)
        self.volume_slider.set(50)
        self.volume_slider.place(y=550, x=screen_width/2, anchor="center")
        # self.volume_slider_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 550, anchor="center", window=self.volume_slider)

        self.equalizer_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#212121")
        self.equalizer_frame.place(x=screen_width/2, y=600, anchor="center")

        # self.equalizer = vlc.AudioEqualizer()
        self.create_equalizer_controls()

        self.playlist = None
        self.current_index = None
        self.audio_urls = []
        self.media_list = None
        self.media_player = None

        self.last_playlists_file = "last_playlists.json"
        self.last_playlists = []

        # Bindings for moving and resizing
        self.bind_events()

    def bind_events(self):
        for widget in [self.label, self.playlist_id_entry, self.load_button, self.listbox, self.controls_frame, self.volume_label, self.volume_slider, self.equalizer_frame]:
            widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_widget_click)
            widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
            widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)
            widget.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
            widget.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        self.drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "widget": None}
        self.resize_data = {"resizing": False, "widget": None, "direction": None}

    def on_widget_click(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        self.drag_data["widget"] = widget
        self.drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self.drag_data["y"] = event.y
        if self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            self.resize_data["widget"] = widget

    def on_drag(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        cx=self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx()
        cy=self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty()
        widget.place(x=cx, y=cy)
        
        """widget = self.drag_data["widget"]
        if widget and not self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            x = widget.winfo_x() + event.x - self.drag_data["x"]
            y = widget.winfo_y() + event.y - self.drag_data["y"]
            widget.place(x=x, y=y)
        elif self.resize_data["resizing"]:
            self.resize_widget(event)"""

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.drag_data["widget"] = None
        self.resize_data["resizing"] = False

    def on_enter(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.update_idletasks()
        bbox = widget.winfo_geometry().split('+')[0].split('x')
        width = int(bbox[0])
        height = int(bbox[1])

        if abs(event.x - width) < 5 or abs(event.y - height) < 5:
            self.canvas.config(cursor="sizing")
            self.resize_data["resizing"] = True
        else:
            self.canvas.config(cursor="")

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(cursor="")

    def resize_widget(self, event):
        widget = self.resize_data["widget"]
        widget.update_idletasks()
        width = widget.winfo_width()
        height = widget.winfo_height()

        if abs(event.x - width) < 5:
            widget.config(width=event.x)
        elif abs(event.y - height) < 5:
            widget.config(height=event.y)

    def load_playlist(self):
        def load_playlist_async():
            try:
                playlist_id = self.playlist_id_entry.get().split('&')[0]
                if not playlist_id:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a valid playlist ID")
                    return

                playlist_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={playlist_id}"
                self.playlist = self.get_playlist_videos(playlist_url)

                self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
                for title in [video['title'] for video in self.playlist]:
                    self.listbox.insert(tk.END, title)

                self.current_index = 0
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading playlist: {e}")
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to load playlist: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=load_playlist_async).start()

    def get_playlist_videos(self, playlist_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'extract_flat': True,
            'quiet': True,
            'force_generic_extractor': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            result = ydl.extract_info(playlist_url, download=False)
            if 'entries' in result:
                return result['entries']
            else:
                return []

    def play_all(self):
        def play_all_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist first")
                    return
                self.current_index = 0
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_all: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_all_async).start()

    def play_selected(self):
        def play_selected_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist")
                    return
                selected_index = self.listbox.curselection()
                if selected_index:
                    self.current_index = selected_index[0]
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_selected: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_selected_async).start()

    def play_current_index(self):
        def play_current_index_async():
            try:
                if self.current_index is None or self.current_index >= len(self.playlist):
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a valid video")
                    return
                video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={self.playlist[self.current_index]['id']}"
                audio_url = self.get_best_audio_url(video_url)
                media = self.vlc_instance.media_new(audio_url)
                self.player.set_media(media)
                self.set_volume(self.volume_slider.get())
                self.player.play()
                self.highlight_current_song()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_current_index: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=play_current_index_async).start()

    def get_best_audio_url(self, video_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio',
            'quiet': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
            return info_dict['url']

    def highlight_current_song(self):
        try:
            self.listbox.select_clear(0, tk.END)
            self.listbox.select_set(self.current_index)
            self.listbox.activate(self.current_index)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in highlight_current_song: {e}")

    def pause_audio(self):
        try:
            if self.player.is_playing():
                self.player.pause()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in pause_audio: {e}")

    def on_song_end(self, event):
        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index < len(self.playlist):
            self.play_current_index()

    def skip_forward(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_forward: {e}")

    def skip_back(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index - 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_back: {e}")

    def shuffle_playlist(self):
        try:
            if self.playlist:
                random.shuffle(self.playlist)
                self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
                for video in self.playlist:
                    self.listbox.insert(tk.END, video['title'])
                self.current_index = 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in shuffle_playlist: {e}")

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        try:
            self.player.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in set_volume: {e}")

    def save_playlist(self):
        try:
            playlist_id = self.playlist_id_entry.get().split('&')[0]
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if playlist_id and playlist_id not in self.last_playlists:
                self.last_playlists.append(playlist_id)
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "w") as file:
                    json.dump(self.last_playlists, file)
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Playlist saved successfully")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Playlist is already saved")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in save_playlist: {e}")

    def load_last_playlists(self):
        try:
            if os.path.exists(self.last_playlists_file):
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "r") as file:
                    self.last_playlists = json.load(file)
            else:
                self.last_playlists = []
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_last_playlists: {e}")

    def load_saved_playlist(self):
        try:
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if not self.last_playlists:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "No saved playlists found")
                return

            playlist_id = random.choice(self.last_playlists)
            self.playlist_id_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.playlist_id_entry.insert(0, playlist_id)
            self.load_playlist()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_saved_playlist: {e}")

    def create_equalizer_controls(self):
        labels = ["60Hz", "170Hz", "310Hz", "600Hz", "1kHz", "3kHz", "6kHz", "12kHz", "14kHz", "16kHz"]
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            lbl = tk.Label(self.equalizer_frame, text=label, fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
            lbl.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

            scale = tk.Scale(self.equalizer_frame, from_=-20, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=70, command=lambda val, idx=i: self.set_equalizer_band(idx, val))
            scale.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

    def set_equalizer_band(self, band, value):
        try:
            self.equalizer.set_amp_at_index(float(value), band)
            self.player.set_equalizer(self.equalizer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error setting equalizer band: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = YouTubeJukebox()
    app.mainloop()

I used the place method to position widgets instead of creating widgets in a canvas.
will help : https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pack-place-and-grid-in-tkinter/

First and foremost thank you for your help. I appreciate you taking your time to attempt to help me.But when clicking on windows in this method they randomly resize in unpredictable manners. And when trying to move widows to left side of the screen, you can not even place objects where you want them. Movements are jerky and not smooth

Which widget are you talking about, all widgets or a specific one? can you update your question with an image ? it will helpfull.

Thank you for the compliment. We are here to help each other.

I edited the answer. I commented out the VLC library stuff because it kept throwing an error.

See image for how I move and place widgets around the screen. It will not open that way you have to move the widgets to place them there to not have a cluttered bunched up look. See the song listbox I want to be able to grab edges and make it the dimensions i want. Taller, wider, or shorter and not as wide. Same with Equalizer and play buttons bar etc

Put dependencies list and image in original post

I already installed vlc.I think problem with python version.
I added a new answer. It changes your code further. I added it as a separate answer.

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import os
# import vlc
import random
import json
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


import tkinter as tk

class DraggableResizableWidget:
    def __init__(self, widget_type, **kwargs):
        self.widget = widget_type(**kwargs)
        self.init_drag_and_resize()

    def init_drag_and_resize(self):
        self.widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)
        self.widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
        self.widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

        self.widget.bind("<Button-3>", self.on_click_resize)
        self.widget.bind("<B3-Motion>", self.on_resize)

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.widget.startX = event.x
        self.widget.startY = event.y

    def on_drag(self, event):
        cx=self.widget.master.winfo_pointerx() - self.widget.master.winfo_rootx()
        cy=self.widget.master.winfo_pointery() - self.widget.master.winfo_rooty()
        self.widget.place(x=cx, y=cy)

    def on_release(self, event):
        pass

    def on_click_resize(self, event):
        self.widget.startX = event.x
        self.widget.startY = event.y
        self.widget.start_width = self.widget.winfo_width()
        self.widget.start_height = self.widget.winfo_height()

    def on_resize(self, event):
        new_width = self.widget.start_width + (event.x - self.widget.startX)
        new_height = self.widget.start_height + (event.y - self.widget.startY)
        self.widget.place(width=new_width, height=new_height)


class YouTubeJukebox(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



        self.title("YouTube Jukebox by Littch")
        
        # Detect screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # Set geometry to maximize the window
        self.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
        
        # Load background image
        self.bg_image = Image.open(r"F:\\Wallpapers\\Desktop\\wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper (1).jpg")
        self.bg_image = self.bg_image.resize((screen_width, screen_height), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.bg_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bg_image)

        # Create a canvas and set the background image
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.bg_photo, anchor="nw")

        # VLC Instance and Player Setup
        # self.vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
        # self.player = self.vlc_instance.media_player_new()
        # self.player.event_manager().event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.on_song_end)

        # Styling
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure('TButton', font=('Arial', 7), padding=5)
        style.map('TButton', foreground=[('pressed', 'white'), ('active', 'white')],
                  background=[('pressed', '#3498DB'), ('active', '#3498DB')])

        self.playlist_id_entry_style = {"bg": "#ECF0F1", "fg": "#34495E", "insertbackground": "#34495E"}
        self.playlist_id_label_style = {"bg": "#2C3E50", "fg": "#FFFFFF"}

        # Add widgets to the canvas
        self.label = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Label, master=self, text="Enter YouTube Playlist ID:", **self.playlist_id_label_style)
        self.label.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=50, anchor="center")
        
        self.DraggableResizableWidget = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Entry ,master=self, width=50, **self.playlist_id_entry_style)
        self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=100, anchor="center")
        
        self.load_button = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=ttk.Button, master=self, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_playlist)
        self.load_button.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=150, anchor="center")
        
        self.listbox = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Listbox, master=self, width=80, height=15, bg="#424242", fg="#FFFFFF", selectbackground="#FF5722")
        self.listbox.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=300, anchor="center")

        self.controls_frame = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Frame, bg="#212121")
        self.controls_frame.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=450, anchor="center")
        button_style = {'width': 6, 'height': 1}

        self.play_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Play", command=self.play_selected)
        self.play_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.pause_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Pause", command=self.pause_audio)
        self.pause_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.play_all_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Play All", command=self.play_all)
        self.play_all_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_back_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Skip Back", command=self.skip_back)
        self.skip_back_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.skip_forward_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Skip Forward", command=self.skip_forward)
        self.skip_forward_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.shuffle_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Shuffle", command=self.shuffle_playlist)
        self.shuffle_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Save Playlist", command=self.save_playlist)
        self.save_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.load_playlist_button = ttk.Button(self.controls_frame.widget, text="Load Playlist", command=self.load_saved_playlist)
        self.load_playlist_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.volume_label = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Label, master=self, text="Volume:", fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
        self.volume_label.widget.place(y=500, x=screen_width/2, anchor="e")
        #self.volume_label_window = self.canvas.create_window(200, 500, anchor="center", window=self.volume_label.widget)
        self.volume_slider = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Scale, master=self, from_=0, to=100, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.set_volume, length=300 )
        self.volume_slider.widget.set(50)
        self.volume_slider.widget.place(y=550, x=screen_width/2, anchor="center")
        # self.volume_slider_window = self.canvas.create_window(screen_width//2, 550, anchor="center", window=self.volume_slider.widget)
        self.equalizer_frame = DraggableResizableWidget(widget_type=tk.Frame, master=self, bg="#212121")
        self.equalizer_frame.widget.place(x=screen_width/2, y=600, anchor="center")

        # self.equalizer = vlc.AudioEqualizer()
        self.create_equalizer_controls()

        self.playlist = None
        self.current_index = None
        self.audio_urls = []
        self.media_list = None
        self.media_player = None

        self.last_playlists_file = "last_playlists.json"
        self.last_playlists = []

        # Bindings for moving and resizing
        #self.bind_events()

    def bind_events(self):
        for widget in [self.label.widget, self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget, self.load_button.widget, self.listbox.widget, self.controls_frame.widget, self.volume_label.widget, self.volume_slider.widget, self.equalizer_frame.widget]:
            widget.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
            widget.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)



    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(cursor="")
        
    def load_playlist(self):
        def load_playlist_async():
            try:
                playlist_id = self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget.get().split('&')[0]
                if not playlist_id:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter a valid playlist ID")
                    return

                playlist_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={playlist_id}"
                self.playlist = self.get_playlist_videos(playlist_url)

                self.listbox.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
                for title in [video['title'] for video in self.playlist]:
                    self.listbox.widget.insert(tk.END, title)

                self.current_index = 0
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading playlist: {e}")
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to load playlist: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=load_playlist_async).start()

    def get_playlist_videos(self, playlist_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'extract_flat': True,
            'quiet': True,
            'force_generic_extractor': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            result = ydl.extract_info(playlist_url, download=False)
            if 'entries' in result:
                return result['entries']
            else:
                return []

    def play_all(self):
        def play_all_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist first")
                    return
                self.current_index = 0
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_all: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_all_async).start()

    def play_selected(self):
        def play_selected_async():
            try:
                if not self.playlist:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please load a playlist")
                    return
                selected_index = self.listbox.widget.curselection()
                if selected_index:
                    self.current_index = selected_index[0]
                self.play_current_index()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_selected: {e}")
        threading.Thread(target=play_selected_async).start()

    def play_current_index(self):
        def play_current_index_async():
            try:
                if self.current_index is None or self.current_index >= len(self.playlist):
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a valid video")
                    return
                video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={self.playlist[self.current_index]['id']}"
                audio_url = self.get_best_audio_url(video_url)
                media = self.vlc_instance.media_new(audio_url)
                self.player.set_media(media)
                self.set_volume(self.volume_slider.widget.get())
                self.player.play()
                self.highlight_current_song()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in play_current_index: {e}")

        threading.Thread(target=play_current_index_async).start()

    def get_best_audio_url(self, video_url):
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio',
            'quiet': True
        }
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
            return info_dict['url']

    def highlight_current_song(self):
        try:
            self.listbox.widget.select_clear(0, tk.END)
            self.listbox.widget.select_set(self.current_index)
            self.listbox.widget.activate(self.current_index)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in highlight_current_song: {e}")

    def pause_audio(self):
        try:
            if self.player.is_playing():
                self.player.pause()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in pause_audio: {e}")

    def on_song_end(self, event):
        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index < len(self.playlist):
            self.play_current_index()

    def skip_forward(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_forward: {e}")

    def skip_back(self):
        try:
            if self.current_index is not None:
                self.current_index = (self.current_index - 1) % len(self.playlist)
                self.play_current_index()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in skip_back: {e}")

    def shuffle_playlist(self):
        try:
            if self.playlist:
                random.shuffle(self.playlist)
                self.listbox.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
                for video in self.playlist:
                    self.listbox.widget.insert(tk.END, video['title'])
                self.current_index = 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in shuffle_playlist: {e}")

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        try:
            self.player.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in set_volume: {e}")

    def save_playlist(self):
        try:
            playlist_id = self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget.get().split('&')[0]
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if playlist_id and playlist_id not in self.last_playlists:
                self.last_playlists.append(playlist_id)
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "w") as file:
                    json.dump(self.last_playlists, file)
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Playlist saved successfully")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Playlist is already saved")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in save_playlist: {e}")

    def load_last_playlists(self):
        try:
            if os.path.exists(self.last_playlists_file):
                with open(self.last_playlists_file, "r") as file:
                    self.last_playlists = json.load(file)
            else:
                self.last_playlists = []
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_last_playlists: {e}")

    def load_saved_playlist(self):
        try:
            self.load_last_playlists()
            if not self.last_playlists:
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", "No saved playlists found")
                return

            playlist_id = random.choice(self.last_playlists)
            self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.DraggableResizableWidget.widget.insert(0, playlist_id)
            self.load_playlist()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in load_saved_playlist: {e}")

    def create_equalizer_controls(self):
        labels = ["60Hz", "170Hz", "310Hz", "600Hz", "1kHz", "3kHz", "6kHz", "12kHz", "14kHz", "16kHz"]
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            lbl = tk.Label(self.equalizer_frame.widget, text=label, fg="#FFFFFF", bg="#212121")
            lbl.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

            scale = tk.Scale(self.equalizer_frame.widget, from_=-20, to=20, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=70, command=lambda val, idx=i: self.set_equalizer_band(idx, val))
            scale.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=2, pady=2)

    def set_equalizer_band(self, band, value):
        try:
            self.equalizer.set_amp_at_index(float(value), band)
            self.player.set_equalizer(self.equalizer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error setting equalizer band: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = YouTubeJukebox()
    app.mainloop()

Use button-3 (rigth mouse button) for resize widgets and use button-1 for drag widges.

Thank YOU! I now have what I intended when I set out on this mad idea a week ago lol

I'm glad to hear that you achieved what you want.

i do not know what vlc error you were experiencing because all i did was un comment the lines for vlc you had commented out and insert my background image in to your corrected script and it is literally playing as i type this. Moved my windows and resized them as I wanted perfectly. So must be you need to update your vlc version in Python? Reason I wanted it is it runs in background, uses less resources, I also do not have to download music to my hard drive just create a playlist on youtube and have music galore to listen to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705830/can-not-import-vlc-to-python-program
The error i am getting. nevermind i don't want to use vlc anyway,
